# How to Load balance using nginx and apache?

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I have three server. One is for load balance another two is for viewing my site. Normally when i load the load balancing ip it works fine. but when i click on some link to do another work it does not work. it gives me 404.
In my other two server they have apache installed. What is the problem. How can i make my web page workable.
my nginx load balancer default code is

```
upstream web_backend{
    server 192.168.33.2;
    server 192.168.33.3;
}

server{
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web_backend;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try to access some link directly without load balancing, does it work e.g. 192.168.33.2/somelink ?Could it be that your actual backend servers aren't set up correctly?

Comment: 192.168.33.2/folder_name works fine but my .htaccess not redirect to index file 
Locally my project works fine

Comment: Does each one of your backend servers always work properly and return the expected pages (without going through nginx)? It looks like your problem is with one of your apache servers (check the logs and enable access log / debug if needed)

Answer (score 0):

there is a good article, look at this page: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-load-balancing